# Splitting out keywords for company names into separate words

Tags: seo, meta-tags

Where do I draw the line on meta keywords separation? For example, if my company name is acme industries, do search engine crawlers come along and look at each comma separated value as a separate entity?

IE:

`<meta name="keywords" content="acme, acme industries" />`

Is it best to do the above or just something as simple as this?

`<meta name="keywords" content="acme industries" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one great example for you: Pick the BEST title tags for the important (keywords). I'll put my answer in spoiler, so if you answered correctly, you are understanding the principles of SEO, and therefore you can answer your question by yourself. Check this out:

`"Charlie Sheen"` `"Winning"` `"Howard Stern Show"` when optimizing will look like:

1. Charlie Sheen Winning on the Howard Stern Show
2. Howard Stern Show & Charlie Sheen | Winning
3. Charlie Sheen is Winning Points on the Howard Stern Show
4. Charlie Sheen | Winning | Howard Stern Show
5. Charlie Sheen and Howard Stern Winning the Show
6. Winning | Charlie Sheen on the Howard Stern Show
7. Charlie Sheen Winning | Howard Stern Show
8. Doesn't matter as long as the words are all there

**ANSWER:**

> 4. is the correct answer.

Comment: Good suggestion except one thing (not to be a spoiler). Only Yandex uses the keywords meta tag. It is generally far better to not bother with this meta-tag at all.

Comment: @closetnoc Good to know. Do you have a source that Google/Bing/etc don't use the keywords meta tag?

Comment: This has been common knowledge for well over a decade. I used to know where there was a good list of who used the keywords meta-tag, but I cannot find it anymore. Bing (and Yahoo! by extension using Bing search data), and Google officially do not support Keywords meta-tag. You will find opinions about Bing all over the place including a statement that Bing considers it a signal. For search engines, all you have to ask yourself is, "Can I manipulate results?" If the answer is Yes, then search engines will ignore the manipulated element.

Comment: For the record, I do not follow the SEO so-called expert parrots. I have been researching and testing on my own including reading patents, research papers, books published by engineers, etc. As well, I am very aware of the technologies used in search engines and have built a few niche search engines with data from G and was privy to some internal G documents in the past. As well, I have worked on technologies used in Internet Trust Systems with G where G used the results. I am a retired systems internals engineer with Bell Labs, DEC Labs, and BT Labs and know how these things must work.

Comment: BTW- For a long time, I argued that it was far easier to disable code than remove it and far easier not to reorder a large scale index than remove data. Even easier still, it is far simpler to not modify code or an index and continue to collect data but just ignore the data. For a while, this was probably %100 true for everyone. Google I am sure updated their systems, but I will not swear to anyone else working so hard. Bing is just a rebranding of MSN and clearly not a full rewrite. But Google has made large scale DB changes over the years. One reason why they won the search war.